# Creation and annihilation operators in QFT explained

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, second-quantization

I'm currently self studying QFT from Matthew D. S textbook and David Tongs online notes. I have trouble understanding the creation/annihilation operators in the QFT formalism. I couldn't find any equation of the $a_p$ and $a_q$, where $p$ and $q$ are momentum 3-vectors. What is there meaning (physically or analogically?). Is there any equation of $a_p$ = and $a_q$ ?

Comment: Do you recall the formalism of these operators from quantum mechanics and the harmonic oscillator?

Comment: I understand the operators in the Schrodinger formalism where they are used as ladder operators switching to the upper or lower quantum state. What's the difference in these operators? Also, does q and p represent space and conjugate momentum in the indices? or is it just a simple for a different vector?

Comment: Related,  possibly slightly, sorry....https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/415433/annihilation-and-creation-operators-in-qft.   But this is better, I think https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412568/creation-and-annihilation-operators-in-qft

Comment: Hint: use the relation between $\phi$ and $\pi$ on one hand and $a_p$ and $a_p^{\dagger}$ on another. Invert the relation to get the expressions for $a_p$ and $a_p^{\dagger}$.